# Magnetostatics and electrostatics orbiting a star with a magnetic field

Tags: special-relativity, electrostatics, astrophysics, orbital-motion, magnetostatics

I understand from the Feynman notes on physics that a static magnetic field in one frame of reference becomes a static electric field in a reference frame in which I move at the same speed as the drift velocity of the charge that produces the magnetic field in the initial frame of reference.

Question:  does this effect or something analogous apply if I'm in a circular orbit around an object that in a rest frame has a static magnetic field?  For example if I'm orbiting a star or planet with a magnetic field produced by a current within it, if I orbit at some speed* that effectively matches the drift velocity of the current in the object will it have in my frame of reference a static electric field?

*going out on limb to say my orbital speed should be such that my angular velocity is the same as the angular drift velocity of the current

Comment: I think you'll get into some trouble here trying to use special relativity because, if you are in a circular orbit, you are no longer in an inertial frame. You are constantly accelerating. Though you might be able to use something like infinitesimal steps where each step is an inertial frame. I saw this is principles of electrodynamics by Melvin Schwartz.

Comment: Agree completely hence why I posted the question here.  I tried to be careful to not use special relativity in the question but happy to reword if you have suggestions.  The principle I'm interested in is the switch between static magnetic and static electric field, does that happen in a circular orbit, regardless of what form of relativity required.  Or maybe the switch doesn't happen.